# Free screen saver for dual monitor system

Tags: software-rec, multiple-monitors, screensaver

Finally I outfit my system with dual screens, After I spent over hour and half for setting good looking desktop background, Now I want to try some cool screen saver that can use dual motors individually. My OS WINXP and graphic card is Nvidia 5800. Is there any recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime I need say to myself Let Me Google That for You,
So far I found this [Really Good](http://www.reallyslick.com/) sets of open source screensavers.